# Catching exception of an invoke async method C#

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, exception

I'm trying to get an exception from an async method that I need to invoke, example:

```
public async Task MyFirstMethod()
{
     await Check(() => Test("test"));
}

        private async Task<TResult> Check<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Run(() => function());
                ...
            }
            catch(Exception exception)
            {
                <<<Reach here>>>
            }
        }

private async Task<string> Test(string s)
{
    await Task.Run(() => s.ToList());
    throw new Exception("Exception Test");
}
```

This works if the Test method is not async and I just call function() in the Check method.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

**Solution:** Changing
`private async Task<TResult> Check<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)` to `private async Task<TResult> Check<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> function)`

Comment: The question and motives are a little unclear.

Comment: My gut feeling is you just want `private async Task<TResult> Check<TResult>(Func<Task<TResult>> function) {return await function()}` However, all bets are off until you clarify what you are trying to do

Comment: You need to be _very_ careful when using `Task.Run()` with theoretically async methods, as there are overloads for `Task.Run()` that specifically handle _tasks_ differently than non-asynchronous scenarios.

Comment: What I want to achieve is run Check, with any method I pass as a parameter, invoke it and check if it launches any exception. @TheGeneral

Comment: I think you will find it very illuminating to add `Debug.WriteLine($"typeof(TResult): {typeof(TResult).Name}");` to your `Check<TResult>()` method. I will bet that you are not expecting `TResult` to be `Task<string>`, but it is. Which means that you need to await the _result_ value itself (i.e. the value returned by the expression `await Check(...)`) to observe the exception. Until you do that, the exception is still wrapped up in the task where it happened.

Comment: In other words, change the parameter to `Check` to be a `Func<Task<TResult>>` instead of a `Func<TResult>`.

Comment: You should have included the `return` statements inside the `Check` and `Test` methods. They are important for understanding the intention of the code.

Comment: As a side note, according to the [guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/asynchronous-programming-patterns/task-based-asynchronous-pattern-tap#naming-parameters-and-return-types) the asynchronous methods `MyFirstMethod`, `Check` and `Test` should have the `Async` suffix (`MyFirstMethodAsync`, `CheckAsync` and `TestAsync`). This suffix helps at reducing the confusion between normal and asynchronous methods.

Answer (score -3):

This happens because you're not catching exceptions where they are thrown (in the same context).

Try this

```
private async Task<TResult> Check<TResult>(Func<TResult> function)
{
        await Task.Run(() => {
           try 
           {
              function();
           }
           catch(Exception exception)
           {
              // do whatever
           }
        });
}
```

Comment: `function` is asynchronous. That try-catch is as useful as if it wasn't there.